# All controls disabled in title-less window

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, nsresponder, nscontrol

In my app I've got a secondary `NSWindow` that's created from .xib in my `NSWindowController` in my `initWithWindowNibName:` method. The window is a plain `NSWindow` with the title bar switched off.

After creating the window it's shown using `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` -
and all controls are disabled (text field, combo box).

I have (more than..) **triple checked** all flags in the window and the view hierarchy of the controls: everything is enabled, allowing editing and not refusing to be first responder.

Totally clueless. Any ideas?

**Update #1:**
I appears the problem is related to the window not having a title bar. When the title bar is switched on the window - and the controls in the window - behave as expected.

Comment: By "all flags", do you just mean the ones which can be set in IB? In particular, if your window doesn't have a title, then `-canBecomeMainWindow` and `-canBecomeKeyWindow` return `FALSE`. You probably need to override them to return `TRUE`.

Comment: @KenThomases Indeed - just the IB flags. Ok, I'll try with a subclass then. Cumbersome, though..

Comment: You mean the only controls in the window are text fields and combo boxes?  Such controls need to be in a key window and become first responder in order to function, whereas other controls like buttons can work without being in a key window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Ken the framework will [automatically refuse becoming a key window](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/canBecomeKeyWindow) if the window title is switched off:

> Attempts to make the window the key window are abandoned if this
>   method returns NO. The NSWindow implementation returns YES if the
>   window has a title bar or a resize bar, or NO otherwise.

A simple subclass did the trick.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the 'subclass' does to fix this?

Comment: override var canBecomeKey: Bool { true }

Comment: @ZS Yeah - as indicated if you read my answer you'd have to override `canBecomeKeyWindow`